# Jquery Modal Dialog displaying MVC3 partial view - works first click only

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

```
 public ActionResult MeanQ(int id)
{            
    Access access= db.Access.Find(id);
    return PartialView("_MeanQPartial", access);
}
```

The partial view thats being rendered in the above code is displayed in a Dialog Modal (Jquery)...The link(onclick) that displays the partial view in a Jquery Modal Dialog works well for the first click. Once I close that dialog and click on the link again, the Partial View  does not open as expected in a pop up form. It opens as a new page in the browser. How can I make the pop up modal dialog link work the same way every time?

Javascript code is below (Jquery Modal Dialog):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize the dialog
    $("#result").dialog({ width: 400, resizable: true, position: 'center', title: 'Access info', autoOpen: false,
        buttons: { "Ok": function () { $(this).dialog("close"); } }
    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#modal').click(function () {
        //load the content from this.href, then turn it into a dialog.

        $('#result').load(this.href).dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

HTML Link that triggers the modal dialog:

```
@Html.ActionLink("PopUp", "MeanQ", new { id = item.AccID }, new { id = "modal" })
```

Comment: you need to show jquery/javascript code as well as the html, otherwise it's extremely difficult to actually spot what is wrong.

Comment: An `ActionResult` doesn't control whether it is shown in a new window or not, the browser does via script/markup/browser-config.

Comment: Please see edits to my original post for js code. Thank you

Comment: What does your `<html/>` look like?

Comment: its just an action link:  @Html.ActionLink("PopUp", "MeanQ", new { id = item.AccID }, new { id = "modal" })

Comment: Is `#modal` and child of `#result` or is `#modal` returned in the partial view `_MeanQPartial`?

Comment: @Mark : I am not sure what you mean exactly here, but looks like #modal is a child of #result div. I have one more line I missed just above <Script> tag.. this one  <div id="result"></div> in the code. May be this will answer your question.

Comment: @Mark - Using a delegate as per your code  $("#result").delegate("#modal", "click", function(){ did not work too. I am getting a full blown browser page instead of a jquery dialog box even for the first time.

Comment: This issue is still not fixed... can anyone help please. Thank you

Comment: Thanks to Charlino and Patricia's help.. this issue is solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333851/mvc3-only-first-row-link-works-well-with-jquery-modal-dialog

Answer (score 4):

Recently I also faced a slimier problem where I wanted to use both partial and full razor view. I followed following article to implement my Modal Dialog. And it worked fine.

http://www.matthidinger.com/archive/2011/02/22/Progressive-enhancement-tutorial-with-ASP-NET-MVC-3-and-jQuery.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing your JavaScript, my guess is you are somehow replacing the `<a/>` element when loading the `PartialView` since you mention the `<a/>` does the default action after loading the modal.

e.g.

```
$("#someA").click(function(){
  //loads the modal and replaces #someA
});
```

Try using [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
$("#someA").live("click", function(){
  //loads the modal and replaces #someA, but still works since you used live()
});
```

Even better if the element has a common parent, you can use [`.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
$("#someParentOfA").delegate("#someA", "click", function(){

});
```

Comment: Thank you. Please see edits to my original post - for JS code. I tried the ".live" you suggested, it did not work.

Comment: Thanks to Charlino and Patricia's help.. this issue is solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333851/mvc3-only-first-row-link-works-well-with-jquery-modal-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Are you using MVC3? Instead of returning an "ActionResult" it might help if you return a "PartialViewResult".

Comment: Thanks to Charlino and Patricia's help.. this issue is solved. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333851/mvc3-only-first-row-link-works-well-with-jquery-modal-dialog