# MVC3 - Only first row link works well with Jquery Modal Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

Working with MVC3, Razor, Jquery, Javascript. The below code loops through and displays a table structure with fields and a link. The link on each row, triggers a Jquery Modal Dialog that displays a partial view page as a pop up. But the pop up dialog works only for the first row... the link from second row and down open the page as a full blown web page and not a pop up modal dialog. How to fix this..thanks for any help.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category)
    </td>

    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }, new { id = "modalEdit" })   |             

    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the Jquery Modal Dialog code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //initialize the dialog
    $("#resultEdit").dialog({ modal: true, width: 300, resizable: true, position: 'center', title: 'Edit Information', autoOpen: false, 
    open: function(event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }

    });
});

$(function () {
    $('#modalEdit').click(function () {
        //load the content from this.href, then turn it into a dialog.
        $('#resultEdit').load(this.href).dialog('open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's likely because all your edit links have the same id!

This is going to make jquery act highly unpredictably!

Give your edit links a shared class instead, like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "modalEdit" })
```

and change your selector to :

```
$('.modalEdit').click(function () {
```

Comment: You just beat me to it! Just note that because `class` is a reserved word in C#, you must prefix it with an `@` symbol when adding a class html attribute. E.g. `new { @class = "modalEdit" }`

Comment: Thanks! that worked.. except class needs to be @class. (from Charlinos response)

Comment: righto!  i'm using mvc 2 and vb.net so the syntax is a little different :)  glad it worked!

Answer (score 5):

Try changing the link to use a class rather than an id.

E.g.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }, new { @class = "modalEdit" })
```

and

```
$('.modalEdit').click(function () ...
```

Comment: Thanks so much.. appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have multiple elements with the same ID.
Use a classname instead.