# asp.net mvc 4 Delete dialog box opens only on first item

Tags: jquery-ui, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a listing page in a Partial View.  For each list, I have an Edit and Delete links to open a jQuery dialog box to edit/delete the data.  However, the dialog box only opens on the first item and not working with the rest of the list.

What is missing from what I am doing?

**Partial View Listing**

```
>foreach (var item in Model) {
>   <tr>
>       <td>
>           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReportName)
>       </td>
>       <td>
>           @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Note)
>       </td>
>       <td class="icon"><a id="editReportLink" href="#" title="Edit note"><img src="~/Content/_images/icon_edit.png" /></a></td>
>       <td class="icon"><a id="deleteReportLink" href="#" title="Delete thread"><img src="~/Content/_images/icon_delete.png" /></a></td>
>   </tr>
>}
```

**jQuery Function**

```
$("#delete-button").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: "auto",
        width: "auto",
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
    });

    $("#deleteReportLink").click(function () {
        alert("test");
        $("#delete-button").dialog("open");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you figured it out but I had the same problem and the first answer here helped me to fix it.

[MVC3 - Only first row link works well with Jquery Modal Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6333851/mvc3-only-first-row-link-works-well-with-jquery-modal-dialog)