# How is the register/logon dialog shown in the asp.net mvc 4.0 sample project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

This seems to be the cause why the model dialogs for register/logon are shown:

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink",  data_dialog_title = "Registration" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log on", "LogOn", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "logonLink", data_dialog_title = "Identification" })</li>
```

When I reuse those links and modify them slightly to fit my needs for showing a create view dialog I always get my markup embedded/shown in the webpage but not in a dialog.

That is my code I changed slightly:

```
<p>    
     @Html.ActionLink("Create News", "Create", "News", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "createLink", data_dialog_title = "Create new News" })
</p>
```

and thats the original code in the AccountController:

What I do not understand here is where is the "content" coming from? In my Create action for my NewsController I use the same code but content is always null and even when I directly return a 
PartialView() still no dialog is shown instead the markup is displayed in the webpage?

```
public ActionResult Create()
        {
            string actionName = ControllerContext.RouteData.GetRequiredString("action");
            if (Request.QueryString["content"] != null)
            {
                ViewBag.FormAction = "Json" + actionName;
                return PartialView();
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.FormAction = actionName;
                return View();
            }
        }
```

**VIEW**: Index.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<TBM.WEB.Models.News>

<p>    
     @Html.ActionLink("Create News", "Create", "News", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "createLink", data_dialog_title = "Create new News" })
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PublishDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr> 

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PublishDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.Id }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

**PARTIAL-VIEW:** Create.cshtml

```
@model TBM.WEB.Models.News

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>News</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PublishDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PublishDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PublishDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: Please post your view and partial view.

Comment: Yes I have a News model. As I said the markup/view is shown as a partial inside the page, but not in the dialog, but I use the same code the register/logon uses from the asp.net mvc 4.0 sample project. I updated my initial post with view code!

Comment: Ok, what are the names of the view and partial view?  Do you have a Create view for News?

Comment: I found out that both register/logon links ids 'registerLink' and 'logonLink' are also written in the AjaxLogix.js file which I thought its a jquery library but it seems to be a helper classes. I added my 'createLink' but it does not help... seems the AjaxLogin.js is not used...

Comment: Does this functionality have to be a modal popup?

Comment: yes I want all Create/Edit as modal dialogs and actually it should work the way register/logon work magically somehow...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery Modal Dialog displaying MVC3 partial view - works first click only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296720/jquery-modal-dialog-displaying-mvc3-partial-view-works-first-click-only)

Comment: Don't you find a solution for this problem? I'm facing the same problem right now. Thanks for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may need to take a look at the AjaxLogin.js file within the Scripts folder of the sample project. It will need some customization as there is a list of link ids that will utilize a dialog.

Comment: seems someone has the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6296720/jquery-modal-dialog-displaying-mvc3-partial-view-works-first-click-only I close this thread now as its a dupe!